# Oracle stored procedure - CASE v_Variable WHEN 'value' OR 'value' THEN

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Here is a bit of pseudocode to explain what I am looking to do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sproc
(
   v_input IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
 , refCursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS

CASE v_input
  WHEN 'A' THEN
    OPEN refCursor FOR
      SELECT ... FROM ...;

  WHEN 'B' OR 'C'
    OPEN refCursor FOR
      SELECT ... FROM ...;
END CASE;
END sproc;
```

How can I accomplish this 'WHEN 'B' OR 'C' clause?

Comment: Put 'B' or 'C'  inside bracket withTHEN

Comment: `case when V_input = 'A' then.... When V_INPUT in 'B' or V_INPUT = 'C' then`....  OR `WHEN V_INPUT in ('B','C')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only use one condition per `when` using that syntax. But, if you include the conditional variable in the `when` you can specify more values:

```
CASE 
  WHEN v_input = 'A' THEN
    OPEN refCursor FOR
      SELECT ... FROM ...;    
  WHEN v_input IN ('B','C')
    OPEN refCursor FOR
      SELECT ... FROM ...;
END CASE;
```

---

The distinction (as pointed out by xQbert) between simple case statements and searched case statements is specified in the SQL-92 (or later) standard. While the actual reasoning could probably be found with enough work, my conjecture is this:

I think it was about consistency: everywhere else in SQL, Boolean operators like `or` and `and` require complete comparisons such as `x = 1 or y = 2`. The Boolean operators can never be used strictly on operands, such as `x = (1 or 3)`. In the simple case syntax, the comparison is broken up, which forces a choice: they could either 1) only support equality (no `in`, `<>`, `<`, etc.; no Boolean operators) or 2) come up with a special syntax for operators that only applies within simple case statements (and, probably, come up with a nomenclature other than "simple").

Comment: They are different uses of a case statement.  using case when then variable allows you to use complex/compound conditions that case when doesn't.  See [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems004.htm)  Searched case expression vs case expression. The searched CASE expression allows multiple comparisons using multiple variables.

Comment: Allan, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IF` and `IN` statement

```
create or replace procedure sproc(
    v_input in varchar2 default null ,
    refcursor out sys_refcursor )
as
begin
  if v_input = 'A' then
    open refcursor for select ... from ...;
  elsif v_input in ('B','C') then
    open refcursor for select ... from ...;
  end if;
end sproc;
/
```